# Prove: $|xy|=|x|\cdot |y|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Can you help me to prove this equality?
$$|xy|=|x|\cdot |y|$$

I don't know how to start proving the equality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the fact that $\lvert a \rvert = \sqrt{a^2}$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$, we obtain
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\lvert xy \rvert
  &=& \sqrt{ (xy)^2 } \\
  &=& \sqrt{ x^2 \cdot y^2 } \\
  &=& \sqrt{ x^2 } \cdot \sqrt{y^2} \\
  &=& \lvert x \rvert \cdot \lvert y \rvert
\end{array}
$$
for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I don't understand, because surely -a is also a square root of a^2?

Comment: @AndrewDeighton, by convention, the square root function $\sqrt{}$, defined on the domain of non-negative reals, returns the non-negative square root.  This is a valid answer, provided you know that $\sqrt{uv}=\sqrt{u}\sqrt{v}$ when $u$ and $v$ are both non-negative, which $x^2$ and $y^2$ certainly are (assuming $x$ and $y$ are both real).

Comment: of the 4 lines in the proof, lines 2 and 3 are using the equality we are trying to prove.  It happens here that we are using 'positive square root', i.e a square root with notional absolute lines around it.

Comment: I guess questions live on, even 5 years after asked!! The part that is still fuzzy to me is the ability, in the last line of the proof, to assert $|x| \cdot |y|$ as opposed to just being able to assert $x \cdot y$

Answer (score 5):

If $x$ and $y$ are both positive it is obviously true, and the case of one or both being zero is equally trivial.

If one of them is negative (say $y$), you have $$|xy|=x(-y)=x|y|=|x||y|.$$

If both are negative, you have $$|xy|=(-x)(-y)=|x||y|,$$

which exhausts the possibilities.

Comment: Did someone just downvote *both* answers? Why?

Comment: Your answer uses the right idea but doesn't carry it through clearly. What justifies the last equality in the first line of equations? (I downvoted neither.)

Comment: @EthanBolker Yeah, I see what you mean - I edited accordingly.

Comment: Do you write "$x$ is positive" when $x\geq0$? I ask because some people do that, whereas if it means $x>0$ then this answer is missing at least one case.

Comment: @DavidK Thank you, I added a comment to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

There are three cases to consider depending whether each of $x$ and $y$ is negative, zero, or positive.  First, if either $x=0$ or $y=0$, we have  $$  |xy| = 0 = |x||y|  \text{.}  $$

Then, if both $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, $xy > 0$ and either  \begin{align}
x &< 0, y < 0, \text{ so }  & |xy| &= xy = (-x)(-y) = |x||y|  \text{ or}  \\
x &> 0, y > 0, \text{ so }  & |xy| &= xy = (x)(y) = |x||y|  \text{.}
\end{align}

Finally, if $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs, $xy < 0$ and either  \begin{align}
x &< 0, y > 0, \text{ so }  & |xy| &= -(xy) = (-x)(y) = |x||y|  \text{ or}  \\
x &> 0, y < 0, \text{ so }  & |xy| &= -(xy) = (x)(-y) = |x||y|  \text{.}
\end{align}

Comment: I know this is an answer from those heady "pre-Covid" days :-)  The only part I would like some enlightenment on is the first assertion $|xy| = 0 = |x|\cdot|y|$

It's easy to see the first half of the assertion ie $|xy| = 0 $ but I have always found it less understandable of how one specifically gets back to $0 = |x|\cdot|y|$ Any chance of adding some meat to that. Thanks.

Comment: @user1115542 : "if either $x = 0$ or $y = 0$" then either $|x| = 0$ or $|y| = 0$ (respectively), and so $|x| \cdot |y| = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

You are assuming $x$, $y$ are real. To prove for all cases, you must say $x=a+bi$, $y=c+di$. Then you have

$$|xy|=|(ac-bd)+(ad+bc)i|=$$

$$=\sqrt{a^2c^2+b^2d^2-2abcd+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+2abcd}$$

$$=\sqrt{a^2c^2+a^2c^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2}$$

$$=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \cdot \sqrt{c^2+d^2}=|x||y|$$

Comment: Welcome on the MathSE! This site supports Latex. Look, how beautiful became your answer! :-)

Comment: Btw, don't start your answers with "this is not answer" :-) It serves as a red flag for the reviewers, "ok, then we delete it" :-) And your post *is an answer*, because the OP didn't say that he thinks only on the reals.